# Unstacking a Multiindex Pandas DataFrame while keeping same columns

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I'm currently trying to extract text data from a particular column in a data frame and save it to a new data frame. Using the following code snippet I'm able to extract the patterns I want, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to format it the way I like. My current data frame has a multi index and four columns, as shown below. Within the data frame there are between zero and four player names corresponding with each index and I would like them all to be on the same row. In each instance where there are multiple rows corresponding to an index, there is a blank cell in the first row above the player's name that is in the second, and I would simply like to combine these rows and replace the blanks in the first row with the player names (if any) directly below them. Is there any way I could make this happen? Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
regex_df = play_by_play_df['Play'].str.extractall(r'(\. )(.+?)( scored)|(.+?)( homered)|(.+?)( balked to score)|(.+?)( advanced on a wild pitch to score)|(.+?)( advanced on error to score)')[[1,3,5,7,9]].unstack(level='match').stack(level=0)
```

This is the output of that line of code.

```
match                0                1     2     3
2   1    Jason Heyward             None  None  None
13  1      Kolten Wong             None  None  None
38  1   Matt Carpenter             None  None  None
91  3      JD Martinez             None  None  None
94  1              NaN  Yoenis Cespedes  None  None
    3       Alex Avila              NaN  None  None
127 1  Yoenis Cespedes             None  None  None
```

This is what I would like my data frame to look like.

[image: This is my desired output]

My ultimate goal is to extract each player's name that scored on a given play and store that name in a new column. Below are examples of five separate plays that contain the five unique patterns that names are to extracted from:

```
    Play
2   Matt Holliday singled to right (Liner). Jason Heyward scored.
91  JD Martinez homered (Fly).
256 Lorenzo Cain advanced on a wild pitch to score.
331 Billy Hamilton balked to score. Joey Votto advanced to 2B.
8378 Nick Hundley advanced on error to score. DJ LeMahieu advanced to 2B on error. Error by Chris Heston.
```

I would like there to be four additional columns added to this data frame, each containing a player's name that scored (there can be at most four players scoring on a given play). There will obviously be many empty cells because it's rare that there are four players scoring on one play.

Comment: Can you give an example of what your input looks like, and the desired output?

Comment: I edited my question, adding what I would like my desired output to be. I apologize if I misunderstood what you were asking.

Comment: could you paste some text data? it's hard to reproduce the issue just from an image

Comment: @ALollz plus maybe `df = df[0].replace('', np.nan)`,`df = df.dropna(subset=[0])`

Comment: I think you should provide a [mcve] with some of your data starting before the regex and the result you need to obtain. It's possible a lot of this can be fixed with how you define the capture groups in your `regex`, but without knowing what your output columns mean, or what the input is, this just seems like a band-aid fix for another problem.

Comment: can we see `play_by_play_df['Play']`

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguity guys. I updated my question with some of the raw data that I am trying to extract information from. I tried printing the data frame in python and copying the contents but it cut out most of the data from the 'Play' column because of length, so I simply pasted as text.

Comment: did you try `df.dropna(subset=['0'])`?

Comment: @JoshFriedlander I did try your method, however this drops the rows that have NA in the first column as opposed to replacing that NA with the name in the row below

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate all the help guys! Sorry if my question was posed poorly. After doing some digging, I finally fixed my issue. The solution was frustratingly simple.

```
regex_df = play_by_play_df['Play'].str.extractall(r'(\. )(.+?)( scored)|(.+?)( homered)|(.+?)( balked to score)|(.+?)( advanced on a wild pitch to score)|(.+?)( advanced on error to score)')[[1,3,5,7,9]].unstack(level='match').stack(level=0).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
regex_df = regex_df.groupby(regex_df.index).first()
```

All I ended up doing was dropping the first level of the multiindex, making it so there were some rows with the same index. From there, I just used groupby().first() to group by index and force non-NaN values into the top row. My result looks like this:

[image]